# AsyncStorage setItem and getItem confusion

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Basically I used redux to pull some data from Firebase, and need a way to retrieve this data even if there are no nextProps coming in. this.state gets cleared when the screen re-renders. I thought I would give asyncstorage a shot (not sure if this is the right use-case???)

Here is my code:

```
 _loadInitialState = (nextProps) => {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('currentListing', JSON.stringify(nextProps));
    }

    _renderInitialState = async () => {
      try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('currentListing');
        if (value !== null){
    // We have data!!
      return JSON.parse(value);
    }
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
    }
```

This is what I get when I _renderInitialState:

```
{"_40":0,"_65":1,"_55":{"selectedListing":{"listingAttributes":{"avgRating":0,"bio":"Hey","bodyType":"Meso","category":"Endurance","experience":"Btbtt","gender":"Male","location":"somewhere","media":"lmao","name":"Josh","price":"23456","userId":"KruIzhLvPTctEoo8HZWQ2ell4ro2"}}},"_72":null}
```

Why are my keys in numbers, I thought 'currentListing' was supposed to be my key that I set? How do I retrieve the results from the key now?